# Printer is printing Korean characters when Arabic CodePages are specified

Tags: c#, .net, printing

Printer: Yujin Thermal Printer

Library: ESC-POS-.NET (C#)

Different Diagnostics done so far:

- Printed Arabic words using Notepad / Wordpad/ MS Word, Arabic characters prints perfect.
- Printed Arabic characters using wrong codepage, prints question marks as placeholders for Arabic characters.

Code:

```
var e = new EPSON();
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);

var bytes = ByteSplicer.Combine(
                    e.CodePage(CodePage.WPC1256_ARABIC),
                    e.CenterAlign(),
                    e.PrintLine(" Test Page See the Arabic text Below WPC1256_ARABIC"),
                    enc.GetBytes("طباعة صفحة إختبار "),
                    e.PrintLine("\x1D\x56\x42\x00"),
                    e.CodePage(CodePage.PC720_ARABIC),
                    e.CenterAlign(),
                    e.PrintLine(" Test Page See the Arabic text Below PC864_ARABIC"),
                    enc.GetBytes("طباعة صفحة إختبار "),
                    e.PrintLine("\x1D\x56\x42\x00"),
                    e.CodePage(CodePage.PC864_ARABIC),
                    e.CenterAlign(),
                    e.PrintLine(" Test Page See the Arabic text Below PC864_ARABIC"),
                    enc.GetBytes("طباعة صفحة إختبار "),
                    e.PrintLine("\x1D\x56\x42\x00"),
                    e.CodePage(CodePage.PC864_ARABIC),
);`
```

This is the method I use to send bytes to printer. I hope I am not loosing any byte data.

```
public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, byte[] data)
{
    var pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(data.Length); // Allocate unmanaged memory
    Marshal.Copy(data, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, data.Length); // copy bytes into unmanaged memory
    var retval = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, data.Length);
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes); // Free the allocated unmanaged memory

    return retval;
}
```

Output:
[image]

These are the Korean characters that gets printed: "핸 턱한"

I have opened a [github issue](https://github.com/lukevp/ESC-POS-.NET/issues/168) on this as well

Thank you.

Comment: I think that a first place to check would be whether the actual byte sequence for your strings is correct.

Comment: Also, does the korean words printed change when the arabic input is changed too?

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang yes.. I've checked before.

Comment: @ChrisBD can you tell me how to do it? Byte to string conversion and assert?